# Image sequence starting image

Tags: objective-c

I have several identical animations next to each other that needs to start animating at the same time, but I'd like them to start from different images in the array (to avoid the ugly pattern that would create).

Is there no prettier way of achieving that then to rearrange the image array for every animation?

Comment: Show your code or we can't say anything particularly constructive...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing just that btw if anyone ends up reading this.

```
-(NSArray*)shiftedAnimationImageArray:(NSMutableArray*)inputArray{
    int cut = arc4random() % [inputArray count];
    return [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[inputArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(cut, [inputArray count] - cut)] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[inputArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, cut)]]];
}
```

If you're after a particular image to start at, just pass the **cut** to the method instead of randomizing it.